# Obtain unique list entries and their multiplicities in R

Tags: r, list

Given a list, I seek to create a new list with duplicate list entries removed but also wish to store the multiplicity of each unique list entry.

For example, in the following list, I would like to obtain a list of three elements: character(0), "11", "33" "44" and their corresponding multiplicities of 2, 2 and 1, respectively:

```
> list

[[1]]

character(0)

[[2]]

"11" 

[[3]]

"11" 

[[4]]

character(0)

[[5]]

"33" "44"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unique` to get the unique entries and `table` with `match` to get the frequencies:

```
#create list
l <- list(character(0),"11","11",character(0),c("33","44"))

#unique elements
ul <- unique(l)
ul
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "11"

[[3]]
[1] "33" "44"

#get frequencies
table(match(l,ul))

1 2 3 
2 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach works but I worry about it's speed. Aren't unique() and match() rather slow?

Comment: @SAT They call `.Internal` functions, which according to the help are quite magical! But in all seriousness, I think its compiled code so its probably as quick as its going to get. The generality of lists mean that assumptions required for some optimisations can't be relied upon

Comment: I don't think match will work here given this description from the R documentation:  "match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second"

Comment: @SAT The second argument is the unique one so everything in it will be matched to (ie many-to-one mappings) which is why the table can count all the occurances of items in the first vector.

Comment: I'm trying to do something with length(which(l == u1)) for each element of u1. How can I vectorize that?

Comment: You won't be able to compare 2 list with `==` as it's not defined. That construct you show isn't particularly useful either, what problem are you trying to solve with it?